# (funcall ...) Equivalent for Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have a set of functions that take no arguments, e.g.

```
(defn f1 [] 1)
(defn f2 [] 2)
(defn f3 [] 3)
```

I then make a list out of these functions:
`(list f1 f2 f3)`

But how do I run the function returned by something like
`(first (list f1 f2 f3))`?

In Common Lisp I might use `funcall` since `f1` takes no arguments. In Clojure I've tried
`(apply (first (list f1 f2 f3)) ())`, i.e. apply to an empty argument list,
and this works, I indeed get `1`.

But is there a better way to do this? i.e. is there a `funcall` equivalent in Clojure? (Is that even the right question to ask?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment has pointed out, in Clojure all you need is to place the function object as the first (& possibly only) item in a list, written with parentheses.

For clarity, I often prefer to assign the function object to a variable, so it is more obvious what is occurring and counting multiple nesting levels of parens is not so critical.  For example, I would write:

```clj
  (let [fns   [f1 f2 f3]
        f1    (first fns)]
```

and then we get

```
(f1) => 1
```

where you can choose any descriptive name in place of `f1`.

Comment: If you write it out, i'd destructure.